# trajectory of a thrown object

Tags: physics

I have a equation of motion v(t), that is integrated (t=0) to x(t). This symbolizes a trajectory of a thrown object. I want to create compared Plots for x(t) with different values for beta. When I try to Plot this, I always get a straigt line instead a parabola. Could someone help ?

Friction force (Stokes): F = -beta*v

Alternatively how could x(t) could be calculated with DSolve from v(t) ?

thanks so much!

[image]

[image]

I tried this:

```
m = 1;
g = -9.81;
eZ = 1;
beta = 4;
v0 = 18;


x[t_] := (m*v0)/beta*Cos[alpha]*(1 - e^(-(beta/m)*t));
Plot[x, {x, -10, 10}]
```

Comment: You need to specific about what doesn't work, otherwise the question will be closed as incomplete. What did you do, what did you expect to happen, and what happened instead?

Comment: `x` is a function of `t`. You cannot plot `x` for `x`. You must plot `x[t]` for `t`.

Comment: Probably you mean the Euler number by `e`. Within _Mathematica_, this number is called `E` (hint: all built-in symbols start with a capital letter).

Comment: eZ should be the unit vector for z

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Clear[beta]
m = 1;
g = -9.81;
alpha = 2;
bmin = 1;
bmax = 10;
delb = 1;
v0 = 18;
z0 = 0;


x[t_] := (m*v0)/beta*Cos[alpha]*(1 - E^(-(beta/m)*t));
z[t_] := z0 - m g/beta + (m v0/beta Sin[alpha] + m^2 g/beta^2) (1 - 
 E^(-beta/m t))
gr1 = Table[Plot[x[t], {t, -1, 1}], {beta, bmin, bmax, delb}];
Show[gr1]
gr2 = Table[ParametricPlot[{x[t], z[t]}, {t, -1, 1}], {beta, bmin, bmax, delb}];
Show[gr2]
```

Comment: looks perfect so far, thank you! For variation of beta and different plots, I have to remove the underlines and doublepoints in the equotations ?

Comment: No. Those are essential elements for the function definition.

Comment: Now, I have it, thank you :)

Comment: How could I show different values of beta in one plot ?

Comment: @Tom I introduced some modifications to show a diversity in $\beta$

Comment: That's great, thank you very much Cesareo!